# How to access "[[Entries]]" in node or discord js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

[image: reaction.users]

Attempting to access the key value under 1, but cant seem to get through this [[Entries]] array.

Image above is reaction.users

Code:

```
                var element = reaction.users[1].key
                console.log(element) //undefined
```

Comment: The log suggests that this is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you're dealing with. So use its methods. *[[entries]]* is a representation of the internals of the map chosen by your debugger/console, not an actual property that you could access.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Map.prototype.entries, so the solution would be:

```
var element = reaction.entries()[1][0]
```

```js
t = new Map([["680","clientuser"],["272","user"]]);


console.log([...t.entries()][1][0])
//0 is the key and 1 is the value
```

Answer (score 0):

With this it will work, data would be your variable

```
Array.from(data)
```